# change the way wireframe is diplayed

Tags: 3d-view

I have no clue what i did. In the first picture you can see what i dont want. When in wireframe mode I want to be able to have it look like it does in the 2nd picture. I have no idea what i did but i need help i am a major noob.

[image: how can i get rid of this outline i dont know what i did.]

[image: i want it to look like this when in wireframe mode i dont know what i did]

Comment: maybe you pressed Z to see through the geometry, pressing it again will make it non-see through again.

Answer (score 2):

To optimize the viewport speed, by default Blender does not show all edges in wireframe mode.  To force it to draw all edges on a particular object, go to the *object data* panel of the *properties* view and check *draw all edges* under the *display* rollout.

[image]

Here is an example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to see the wireframe model exactly like in Pic1, then:

Because you are in the edit mode on the second pic you have to go back to Object mode first. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> for that or just select 'Object mode' in the menu section above the timeline viewer.

However you need to formulate your question better to help us help you.